# Restarting NiFi Node Joins Cluster as New Node

Tags: kubernetes, cluster-computing, apache-nifi

I am currently running Apache NiFi as a StatefulSet on Kubernetes. I'm testing to see how the cluster recovers if I kill a pod but am experiencing a problem when the pod (NiFi node) rejoins the cluster.

The node will rejoin as an *additional* node instead of appearing as it's original identity. For example, if I have a 3 node NiFi cluster and kill and restart one pod/NiFi node I will end up with a 4 node cluster with one disconnected.

Before:

[image: Before]

After:

[image: After]

I believe that the NiFi node is identified somehow in a config file which isn't persisting when it is killed. So far I am using persistent volumes to persist the following config files:

- state-management.xml
- authorizers.xml

I haven't persisted nifi.properties (it is dynamically generated on startup a
and I can't see anything in there that could uniquely identify the node).

So I guess, the question is how is the node uniquely identified to the server and where is it stored?

**EDIT: I'm using an external Zookeeper.**

Thank you in advance,

Harry

Comment: how did u created nifi cluster on kubernetes??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each node stores the state of the cluster in the local state manager which by default would be written to a write-ahead-log in nifi-home/state/local. Most likely you are losing the state/local directory on the node being restarted.